# Allow both left and right landscape mode auto orientation unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to allow both left and right landscape modes, with auto orientation in Unity (but obviously don't allow it to orientate to portrait mode)?  I would need it to be applied for all the scenes in my game.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the default orientation to `Auto Rotation` you are given more options within `Allowed Orientations for Auto Rotation`.

[image: orientation]

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason, I should have seen that option ^^